# remote Windows Server 2008 to R2 upgrade question

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

We have a remote server running windows 2008 Enterprise but looking to upgrade to R2 - will this work using remote desktop to the server or will we have to go and get the server out of the rack / add a monitor and keyboard to the server?  Don't want to start the install / upgrade and then discover it hasn't worked!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can but you'd have to be familiar with the [microsoft deployment toolkit](https://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=3bd8561f-77ac-4400-a0c1-fe871c461a89&displaylang=en).  I've done clean installs headless but not an upgrade ( but frankly I would never upgrade a server if I could avoid it).

Comment: I suspect a MDT-guided installation is not what the original poster had in mind when saying "will this work using remote desktop" :-p

Comment: I would suspect it is since he doesn't have a mouse or keyboard attached and he wants to do a remote install

Comment: yes thats right - want to do a remote install without dragging everything out but since not familiar withe the mdt, a visit to the rack may be in order!

Answer (score 1):

Windows Server 2003 R2 was an add-on to Windows Server 2003, so you could install it on an existing system without any particular issue.

Windows Server 2008 R2 is a ***new release*** of Windows Server, so it requires a full operating system upgrade, like going from Windows Vista to Windows 7.

This just can't be done remotely.